# Symfony - Form : Listing Categories by type

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a formType, with EntityType column

```
->add('categorie',        EntityType::class,
     [
                'class'                 => Category::class,
                'choice_label'          => 'title',
                'expanded'              => true,
                'multiple'              => true,
     ])
```

The Category Entity has relation with CategoryType Entity:

CategoryType Table on Database :

```
ID | TITLE
1  | Sport
2  | policy
```

Category Table :

```
ID | TITILE | ID_CATEGORY_TYPE
1  | Soccer | 1
2  |  Rugby | 1
3  |   USA  | 2
4  | Russia | 2
```

I want to list categories by category type on the form createView() to be like this

```
Sport
------
[] Soccer //Type Checkbox
[] Rugby  

Policy
------
[] USA
[] RUSSIA
```

is there any method (on the FormType) the modify the display list by adding TITLE of category type on the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you have to overwrite the choice_widget_expanded block.

ArticleType:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use App\Entity\Category;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('category', null, [
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    // make groups with the CategoryType entity
                    'group_by' => function(Category $category, $key, $value) {
                        return $category->getType()->getName();
                    },
                    // sort the categoryTypes alpabetical
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->join('c.type', 't')
                                ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC');
                    },
                ])
        ;
    }
}
```

extended_form_layout.html.twig:

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded -%}
    {% if '-inline' in label_attr.class|default('') -%}
        <div class="control-group">
            {%- for child in form %}
                {{- form_widget(child, {
                    parent_label_class: label_attr.class|default(''),
                    translation_domain: choice_translation_domain,
                }) -}}
            {% endfor -%}
        </div>
    {%- else -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        <div class="row">
        {% for group_label, choice in choices %}
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <h4>{{ group_label }}</h4>
            {% for choice in choice.choices %}
                {{- form_widget(form[choice.value], {
                        parent_label_class: label_attr.class|default(''),
                        translation_domain: choice_translation_domain,
                    }) -}}
            {% endfor -%}
            </div>
            {% if not(loop.index % 3) %}</div><div class="row">{% endif %}
        {% endfor -%}
        </div>
    </div>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

**Update:** I ended up with the following widget for Symfony ~4.3:

```
{%- block choice_widget_expanded -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for group_label, choice in choices %}
        <h4>{{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? group_label : group_label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}</h4>
        {% for choice in choice.choices %}
            {{- form_widget(form[choice.value]) -}}
            {{- form_label(form[choice.value], null, {translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) -}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded -%}
```

edit.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme edit_form 'extended_form_layout.html.twig' %}

{{ form(edit_form) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please explain what is `choices` on for loop on twig ?

Comment: choices are actually the groups that you form with the 'group_by' option in the ArticleType but they are called choices because this option is ment for the ChoiceType, the parent of the EntityType form-field. I did not get the template working under Symfony 4.3 but i found an alternative way. Which Symfony version do you use?

Comment: I added a widget for Symfony 4.3 in my initial answer.